# Not able to telnet to port 25 from public network, only private

Tags: postfix, amazon-web-services, smtp

I have postfix configured with `inet_interfaces = all`.

The following all work:

```
telnet localhost 25
telnet 172.34.56.78 25 # local IP
telnet 34.56.78.90 # public IP
telnet example.com # domain name
```

And the last three work from any server within the private network. However, if I try either of the last two (public IP, domain) from outside of the private network, nothing happens.

This is on AWS but I've added a security group that allows all traffic from my development computer and I still don't have access.

This is the output for netstat:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      12345/master
```

I'm guessing there is a setting I'm not aware of that restricts access only to computers within mynetworks?

Or maybe this is a hidden issue with AWS that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ISPs block access to port 25 on all destinations but their own servers. This helps stop spammers and spambots (the ones the infect people's computers) from using their network to send spam. You might want to check if your ISP is blocking outbound port 25 connections to anything other then their own servers.

Comment: This is it! Looks like Comcast blocks port 25.